# Mocking out angular.element in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, kendo-grid

I have a controller that has a code snippet like this on controller initialization:

```
$scope.grid = angular.element('#MyGrid').kendoGrid(myData);
```

When I go to run jasmine tests, it dies before I can even get to my test code...the error I am getting is:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.element('#MyGrid').kendoGrid')
```

This makes sense because I obviously don't have the MyGrid element in the DOM. How can I mock out the angular.element call to return a mock object with the kendoGrid method?

Thanks!

Comment: It would not throw such error on missing element. It's something else. That being said - you should not have this in controller. Bad.

Comment: Ok - where would you initialize the kendogrid then?

Comment: Directive, always and only directive. And you should never use CSS selectors like #MyGrid.

Comment: Anyway, I think "undefined is not a constructor" could mean that you it couldn't find core kendo grid (not jQuery `kendoGrid`).

Comment: Thanks, the unit test was missing the kendo reference! I will refactor into a directive and see if there is a way to initialize the grid outside of a selector...legacy code...

Comment: Create simple wrapper directive and in its link function do `link(scope, element) { element. kendoGrid() }`.